# Appending meta value onto post content in WordPress during save_post

Tags: php, actions

The problem seems pretty straight forward: Once the [`save_post` action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) is fired, I would like to append the value of a meta key onto the end of the `post_content` if it's not already found within the post itself.

I've attempted making a call to [`wp_update_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post) from within a function tied to `save_post`, but as many of you will immediately object, `wp_update_post()` contains [`do_action('save_post')`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) and as such creates an infinite loop.

What other way (using the API) exists for one to update the content of a post based on said posts custom values once the post has been saved/edited without invoking a nightmarish infinite loop?

Comment: Have you tried hooking into the `wp_insert_post_data` filter? (Despite the name, it's run during both inserts and updates.)

Comment: @BoltClock That was the route I had started down just after posting this question - I've stumbled onto a working example that could no doubt be improved. I'll share it below.

Answer (score 3):

The initial solution I've found is to tie a filter onto an action like `wp_insert_post_data` and extract other post information from the global `$post` object.

```
// Tack our filter onto the wp_insert_post_data action
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'my_appender' );
function my_appender( $content ) {
  // Bring global $post into scope
  global $post;
  // Get meta value of meta key 'key_name'
  $meta_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key_name', TRUE );
  // If value is not in content, append it onto the end
  if ( stristr( $content['post_content'], $meta_value ) === FALSE )
    $content['post_content'] .= $meta_value;
  // Return filtered content
  return $content;
}
```

I'm certain this could see improvement.

**References**

1. [`add_filter()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter) - "Filters are the hooks that WordPress launches..."
2. [`wp_insert_post_data`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_insert_post_data) - "A filter hook called by the wp_insert_post function..."
3. [`global` keyword](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global) - "The scope of a variable is the context within which it is defined..."
4. [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) - "This function returns the values of the custom fields..."
5. [`stristr()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stristr.php) - "Find first occurrence of a string (Case-insensitive)..."

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. I guess how you implement the check would depend on what exactly that post meta value is.

Comment: @BoltClock Correct. I've intentionally kept this example pretty lightweight. My own production version has all the checks and balances in place.